# How to display the data in Jasper report table passed from DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am working on a project in Java Swing and reporting in Jasper Report.

I have designed the report using Jasper Report and I am calling that report from 
Java Class .
Now I want to send the data in the form of TableModel to set value in report Table but jasper report table is not displaying the table data as set in the form of TableModel.

Even the report file is not opening through JAR . If I am creating the jar The Jasper Report page is throwing the exception.

I want to send the table model data in Report Table as in tableModelData in java code. I am using the following code.

```
   package pmc;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
   import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
   import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
   import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
   import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
   import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRTableModelDataSource;
   import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

   public class SimpleReport1 {

   DefaultTableModel tableModel;

   public SimpleReport1() {
     JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
      TableModelData();
       try {
            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("src/reports/report1.jrxml");
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("src/reports/report1.jasper", new HashMap(),
                new JRTableModelDataSource(tableModel));
        JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
        jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
```

}
}

```
private void TableModelData() {
    String[] columnNames = {"Id", "Name", "Department", "Email"};
    String[][] data = {
        {"111", "G Conger", " Orthopaedic", "jim@wheremail.com"},
        {"222", "A Date", "ENT", "adate@somemail.com"},
        {"333", "R Linz", "Paedriatics", "rlinz@heremail.com"},
        {"444", "V Sethi", "Nephrology", "vsethi@whomail.com"},
        {"555", "K Rao", "Orthopaedics", "krao@whatmail.com"},
        {"666", "V Santana", "Nephrology", "vsan@whenmail.com"},
        {"777", "J Pollock", "Nephrology", "jpol@domail.com"},
        {"888", "H David", "Nephrology", "hdavid@donemail.com"},
        {"999", "P Patel", "Nephrology", "ppatel@gomail.com"},
        {"101", "C Comer", "Nephrology", "ccomer@whymail.com"}
    };
    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SimpleReport1();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("src/reports/report1.jrxml");
```

to:

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("src/reports/report1.jrxml","src/reports/report1.jasper");
```